# Show that if $x=-1$ is a solution of $x^{3}-2bx^{2}-a^{2}x+b^{2}=0$, then $1-\sqrt{2}\le b\le1+\sqrt{2}$

Tags: polynomials, roots, cubics

$$x^{3}-2bx^{2}-a^{2}x+b^{2}=0$$
Show that if $x=-1$ is a solution, then $1-\sqrt{2}\le b\le1+\sqrt{2}$

---

I subbed in the solution $x=-1$, completed the square, and now I'm left with the equation $\left(a-1\right)^{2}+b^{2}=2$

Comment: Can't you just use rational root theorem, thus $b^2$ has to be $\pm1$, and if b is real, b must be 1, which satisfies the inequality. :)

Comment: @MaximeJaccon You can only use the rational root theorem if the coefficients are integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have made a mistake during simplification and/or completing the square.

Substituting $x = -1$ into the given equation, we get

$$\begin{align*}
-1 - 2b + a^2 + b^2 &= 0 \\[0.3cm]
\Rightarrow \;\;\;\;\;\;a^2 + (b-1)^2 &= 2
\end{align*}$$

Since $a^2 \ge 0$,

$$\begin{align*}
(b-1)^2 &\le 2 \\[0.3cm]
\end{align*}$$

Can you take it from here?